# ¿Cómo validar la extensión de una imagen en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Intento validar la extensión de una imagen con javascript, pero no sé en qué estoy fallando, necesito saber dónde colocar la llamada a la función y si está bien lo que estoy haciendo, es con jquery:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  //Cambiar icono del input de tipo file
  $('.input-file').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this),
        $label = $input.next('.js-labelFile'),
        labelVal = $label.html();

        var extensiones = ".png";
        function validar(datos) {
          var ruta = datos.value;
          var extension = ruta.substring(ruta.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
          var extensionValida = extensiones.indexOf(extension);

          if(extensionValida < 0) {
            console.log("Extension no valida");
            return false;
          }else {
            if (element.target.value) fileName = element.target.value.split('\\').pop();
            fileName ? $label.addClass('has-file').find('.js-fileName').html(fileName) : $label.removeClass('has-file').html(labelVal);
            $(".alert").removeClass("invisible");
          }
        }
  //Esto permite el cambio
   $input.on('change', function(element) {
      var fileName = '';
      validar(this);

   });
  });

})();
```

Comment: Cual es el problema? Funciona correctamente(o por lo menos a mi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
if(extensionValida < 0) {
    console.log("Extension no valida");
    return false;
}else {
    if (element.target.value) fileName = element.target.value.split('\\').pop();
        fileName ? $label.addClass('has-file').find('.js-fileName').html(fileName) : $label.removeClass('has-file').html(labelVal);
    $(".alert").removeClass("invisible");
}
```

Si la extensión es válida, estás utilizando `element.target.value` **está variable no existe.**

Sería más sencillo si en vez de pasar la referencia al input, pasara el objeto file. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

### Mi propuesta para este código

```js
var $input = $('#file');
var valid_extensions = ['png', 'jpg'];
    $input.on('change', function (e) {
        var $this = this;
        var files = $this.files;

        // If there is more than one file
        if(files) {
            if ($this.files.length > 1) {

                 // TODO: loop for more one file

            } else {

                var file = this.files[0];
                if(validar_extension(file)) {
                    // TODO: Upload file
                
                    alert('Valid extension');
                } else {
                    
                     // Show Error
                     alert('Invalid extension');
                }

            }
        }
    });

    // CHECK FILE EXTENSION
    function validar_extension(file) {
        var file_name = file.name,
        file_extension = file_name.split('.').pop();

        return valid_extensions.includes(file_extension);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <form class="upload-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="file">Selecciona un archivo</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-file"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="file" id="file" class="input-file form-control">
      </div>
      <span class="form-text d-none validation-msg"></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

He creado la función `validar_extension(file): bool` **que sólo hace lo que tiene que hacer**, decirme si es válida o no la extensión del archivo que recibe.